# WebStorm - starting with Sass step by step

Tags: sass, webstorm, configure

how to configure WebStorm to start with Sass? The best is to not install Ruby, so I should use Gulp as I know. But what to do with it? Have anybody WebStorm and may give me step by step instructions?

I am beginner front-end dev, fresh with Sass and I need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-gulp-and-sass/ - you may find this post helpful. But note that gulp-sass is a wrapper around libsass, there are lots of [known issues](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/search?q=install&type=Issues) installing it... So installing Ruby might be a better option. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html

Comment: Ok, I may do this with Ruby. I have still problem with it. Anyone could help me?

Comment: what problems have you faced?

Comment: I downloaded Ruby Windows Installer, install it and do not know what to do next :)

Comment: just follow instructions from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d243019e400: install sass gem ('gem install scss' or 'gem install sass', depending on the desired language, then set up a file watcher in WebStorm...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Ruby
   https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

2.instal sass: please type in cmd => gem install sass
Instructions: https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass

3.set in webstorm
Setting -> Tools -> File Watcher -> Add SCSS

Program: C:\Ruby25-x64\bin\scss

if you want to be compressed css, write " --style compressed " Continue to write the command Arguments.
Example: $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --style compressed